# cipher suites spring high encryption (aes+camellia no aead)

Tags: spring-boot, security, cryptography

I have a security test with two vulnerabilitys (aes+camellia no aead -> not offered, logjam -> VULNERABLE)

The security test was over a spring boot application, and I have the following configuration in my configuration file:

```
server:
  ssl:
    ciphers: EECDH+CHACHA20,EECDH+AESGCM,EECDH+AES+SHA384,EECDH+AES+SHA256,EECDH+AES,EDH+AES256,!EDH+AESGCM,!EDH+SHA256,HIGH,!aNULL,!eNULL,!EXPORT,!DES,!MD5,!PSK,!RC4,!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,!SHA1,!SHA256,!SHA384
```

I removed the CBC algorithms, because the CBC algorithms were reported to me like a vulnerability.

In the test show me too, logjam vulnerability, but I follow the tutorial:

https://geekflare.com/test-logjam-attack-cve-2015-4000-and-fix/

And I included !EXPORT in my cipher suites

I don't Know What I need to solve logjam (because in all pages i find the same response, and AES Camelia, because I remove CBC algorithms, for other vulnerability).

Answer (score 2):

EDH+AES256 is probably responsible for the logjam detection which means that your JRE is using a DH prime of 1024 bit or less. Either remove that cipher suite or change the prime.

If you're using the Oracle the following might work ([reference](https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html)):

> #### Change default key size of the AlgorithmParameterGenerator and KeyPairGenerator implementations from 1024 to 2048 bits
>
> This change will update the JDK providers to use 2048 bits as the default key size for DSA, RSA, and DiffieHellman instead of 1024 bits when applications have not explicitly initialized the `java.security.KeyPairGenerator` and `java.security.AlgorithmParameterGenerator` objects with a key size.
> To test this change download JDK 9.0.1, 8u151, 7u161, 6u171, or later and set the system property `jdk.security.defaultKeySize` with the algorithm and its desired default key size. For example, to test a DSA default keysize of 2048, specify `"‑Djdk.security.defaultKeySize=DSA:2048"` on the java command-line.

In your case adding `"‑Djdk.security.defaultKeySize=DiffieHellman:2048"` as a command-line flag should work.